# Image Steganography Java

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, steganography

I am trying to decode the data encoded in the image. The encoding works fine and the data size of image also changes but for some reason the decoded data is an empty string. Either the encoded data get lost or this code has some mistake.

```
int temp,tempText=0,x=0,p=0;

    try
    {
        image= ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Encoded.png"));

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    for(int i=0;i<image.getWidth();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<image.getHeight();j++)
        {
            pixels[i][j]=image.getRGB(i, j);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<Width;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<Height;j++)
        {
            temp=pixels[i][j];

            int change=0;   

            for(int k=0;k<4;k++) // 4 iterations for 4bytes of every pixel
            {
                if(k==0)
                {
                    change=1;
                }
                else
                    if(k==1)
                    {
                        change=256;
                    }
                    else
                        if(k==2)
                        {
                            change=65536;
                        }
                        else
                            if(k==3)
                            {
                                change = 16777216;
                            }


                tempText=tempText | (pixels[i][j] & change);

                p++;

                if(p==8) // because character is of 8bits
                {
                    myString.concat(String.valueOf(tempText));// Writing decoded data in string
                    p=0;
                    tempText=0;

                }
            }


        }

 // Writing in file

    try
    {
        file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Retreive.txt");
        fw = new FileWriter(file);

        bw= new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write(myString);
        bw.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Kindly notify me if any mistake I am making or any thing this code is lacking.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where do you initialize Width and Height?

Comment: Hey just have to clear my hands on this stuff.So did your algo LSB replacement worked? and the fault in last character ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.concat` doesn't change the string you call it on, but instead returns a new string. So if you use `myString = myString.concat(...)` instead, you might get better results. If `tempText` contains a character code, you could cast it to a char (since `String.valueOf` returns the string representation of the int):

```
// Writing decoded data in string
// myString = myString.concat(String.valueOf(tempText));
myString += (char) tempText;
```

instead of:

```
myString.concat(String.valueOf(tempText));// Writing decoded data in string
```

Comment: Still no success .. :( . I would like to send you the whole code. you may get a better idea by looking at full program

Comment: Sorry to hear that... Can you put all of your code in your question above (or make it available in some other way)?

Comment: I found you code and I'm looking at it. Are there special requirements for the project2.png file or can any png file be used?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23047/discussion-between-freek-de-bruijn-and-alfred)